# How to fetch data from past 2 week in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, partitioning

I have a table with 6GB of data and it has past 6 years of records (few millions of rows), but I want to collect data from past 2 weeks.

How to fetch All column data from past 2 weeks in the table. There is any Query helps me to get those data or should I do partition, etc? Any help.

Comment: Can you give us an example if the table schema? Does it contain a date field? Do you want whole weeks or a rolling 14 days worth? Please edit your question and provide the query, table definition, any errors you getting and what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds to me like a straight forward select query.

```
Select field1, field2, etc
from tablename
Where datefield > getdate() -14;
```

Substitute the fields you want to select and filter, and the tablename.

I would highly reccomend that you take some time to start reading about sql queries. [W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/deFault.asp) would be a good place to start

Comment: seems like perfectly valid answer. only suggestion would be to use dateadd instead of implicit date math. ie where datefield > dateadd(day,-14,getdate())

Comment: @BobKlimes cheers. Fair call. I wasnt going to go overboard given the detail provided.